# How to stop action bar move up

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3, created new Tabs project, add few fragment for each tab. And then added icon for tabs. Everything look ok.
But,
When i scroll, specifically the Action Bar move up and down. It looks ugly to me. Please look at the screenshot (the title and padding area, which I did't add):

[ugly screen when actionbar move up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8p6F.png)

My questions are:

1. How can I do to stop ActionBar move up and down like that? I want to
   handle it later (maybe hidden and unhidden it when user scroll the
   view like Contact App of Android 5.1).
2. If I can't stop the movement,
   what can I do (with XML file) to get rid of the padding Area?

I'm just starting to learn android, so please forgive me if these questions not good enough.

And here's my main activity layout file (It's original as Android Studio created it):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root layout i.e. modify it like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <!-- rest of your layout here -->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

More on `android:fitsSystemWindows` from Android docs:

> internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such
>   as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to leave
>   space for the system windows. Will only take effect if this view is in
>   a non-embedded activity.
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol
>   fitsSystemWindows.

For the scrolling issue, remove the following line from your fragment layout  -

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

And from your main activity's layout, remove the following line from under toolbar tag -

```
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: I've done as you said, but still not working. [here my project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/koaman7hpyiwcoz/myNote.zip?dl=0). The last item not show when the actionbar at normal position.

Comment: I downloaded your source code and tried a couple of things to make it work. I have edited my answer. Also please note, try using a recyclerview instead of listview. It's the suggested alternative.